# Passing values between .exe file (win form) and class library project

Tags: winforms, parameter-passing, projects

due to the limitation of the vendor software, im calling an exe file which is WinForm (with certain controls like combo boxes and text boxes) and pass the values to another project.

Is this possible?

Comment: For which one of the projects (the WinForms application or the class library) are you able to modify the source code? Or can you edit both of them?

Comment: Hi Cody Gray, i can edit both of them.